# core-ajax with handleAs 'document' error 4xx

Tags: polymer

Is there a way to access to the content of the response of a 'core-ajax handleAs="document" request that receives a '4xx' http status code?

Answer (score 2):

Add an error handler to your *core-ajax* element:

```
<core-ajax on-core-error="{{onError}}" ...>
```

Your callback function receives an event object, lets name it `e`. `e.detail.response` only contains an informative message string, but `e.detail.xhr` contains the original XHR response object.

**Edit:** Additional note when using `handleAs="document"`: In this case an exception is thrown when using Polymer 0.3.4.

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property
>   from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's
>   'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'document').

This is the offending code

```
var response = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.responseText;
```

So the error handling code doesn't check if the response type was set to document.

In this case you may need to use the *core-xhr* element directly.

Comment: If you put handleAs="json" it works as you say but if you put handleAs="document" the error handle is never invoked. You can see it changing the param handleAs -> http://jsbin.com/sorov/2/edit